# What does a dashed resistor symbol mean?

Tags: resistors, symbol

What is the dashed resistor symbol going to the ground shown in the picture?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the accompanying text?

Comment: There's a nice * there and a nice note right there on your picture that tells you exactly what it means. There must be a galvanic path from Vin- to ground. That resistor represents that path.

Comment: A dashed symbol or wire normally means that the part is not always present in the circuit or that it can be left out under certain circumstances. In this case it's meaning **seems** to be that the resistor can be left out if `V_IN-` already has some specific properties.

Comment: Vref needs an input bias path to ground proabably, which may or may not be provided whatever you put on Vin-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2.5V reference zener diode to be biased correctly (it needs a minimum current passing through it to produce an accurate 2.5 volts across it), there must be a dc current path to ground from Vref-.

Comment: Thank you for the kind respnse, but what is the difference between the dashed resistor and a normal resistor?

Comment: If you read the note, you must put a pull-down resistor to the ground at the Vref- input, i.e. you must present some DC impedance on this pin as it shouldn't be floating.

Comment: @SodiumAcetate the dashed lines imply that whatever source drives Vin, it must be dc coupled to ground in other words, the source has an internal resistance to ground and you can't (for instance) capacitively couple a source to that input.